# How to keep track of changes over time of a value in a cell. Self referencing challenge

Tags: google-sheets, self-reference

I've a spreadsheet where I've to track daily changes to a cell containing an integer value and calculate the difference between today's newly fetched data and yesterday's data. I do not need to track difference for more than the last 1 day.

Definition:

I've a google spreadsheet with 2 sheets:

1. "SheetA" display updates
2. "SheetB" today's data automatically imported with =IMPORTDATA(url)

The data structure for daily imported data in "SheetB" looks like this:

|  **key** | **value**  | 
| ABC | 100    |
| DEF | 123    |
|  ...    |   ... |

Data is updated every day at 00:00 CET - This means that every morning opening the spreadsheet it automatically updates values in "SheetB" with fresh data and i lose the data from the day before.

"SheetA" structure

|  **key**  |  **yesterday value** | **today value** | **difference** |
| ABC | 100                         |    107           |  (+or-) 7     |
|  ...    | ....                            |           ....      |         ...            |

"SheetA" has to display the daily change in respect to the previous day. If newly imported data from "SheetB" show an increase of 7, it should display +7 in column "difference". The difference can be negative or positive

How do i calculate the difference in "SheetA" without losing data from the day before? I do not need to keep the whole history. I only need the difference from today's value and yesterday's value. I can modify the sheet however i like. I cannot change the source data, which is a csv imported with =IMPORTDATA

The problem is that i should update yesterday's data after calculating the difference. But i cannot calculate the difference without yesterday's data.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You could use another sheet where you will store yesterday's data.***

So - in order to do this, you can make use of Apps Script's time-driven triggers.

#### Code

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function importYesterday() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID");
  let yesterdaySheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("YESTERDAY");
  let todaySheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("TODAY");
  let data = todaySheet.getRange(ROW, COL, NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS).getValues();
  yesterdaySheet.getRange(ROW, COL, NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS).setValues(data);
}


function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('importYesterday')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(23)
      .create();
}
```

#### Explanation

The code above is composed of two functions:

- `importYesterday` - **which is used to import the data from** `TODAY` **sheet to** `YESTERDAY`.

Since the `IMPORTDATA` recalculates at midnight, the method here chosen to import the data makes use of the `getRange` and `getValues` to *get* the data and of the `getRange` and `setValues` to *paste* the data into the `YESTERDAY` sheet.

Note that this method above is independent of the `IMPORTDATA`'s recalculation - so once you have all the data in the `YESTERDAY` sheet, it will remain there, unless you specifically trigger its change.

So, in order to always get the data from yesterday, the `createTrigger` function was created.

- `createTrigger` - **which is used to *trigger* the execution of** `importYesterday` **function.**

This is done by using the `atHour(23)` method which means that the trigger will run approximately at hour 23.

So essentially, the data is imported into the `YESTERDAY` sheet right before the `IMPORTDATA` recalculates.

#### Next Steps

As for the other calculations in the main sheet, you will simply have to reference the cells from the `TODAY` and `YESTERDAY` sheet.

If you also want to update yesterday's data depending on the other values, you can simply modify the `importYesterday` function to match your needs and/or even create another function specifically for updating the values.

#### Note

You will also have to adapt the `getRange` methods used in `importYesterday` in order to match the range of the data you have.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Time Driven Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange(row, column, numrows, numcolumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).